# Socket.io отключается

Tags: socket.io

Я прикидываю код на сервере и клиенте, после чего в putty пишу node code.js, и работа скрипта начинается, но как я закрываю putty, код перестает работать? Что за хрень?

Answer (score 6):

Вопрос на самом деле Руткодовский и касается исключительно администрирования *никсов. Вы отключаетесь, ваш сеанс закрывается и запущенные в нем процессы.

Вам же нужно запустить `node.js'` в режиме демона/в фоновом режиме. Варианты:

- Воспользоваться довольно удобной оберткой для запуска ноды - модулем `forever`. Установите через `npm` (`npm install forever`) и пользуйтесь на здоровье (`forever start code.js`). Он вам и несколько приложений запустит/остановит и логи аккуратно сложит.
- Решить вопрос по-никсовому, как-то так: `nohup node code.js >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Answer (score -1):

Установи pm2 глобально и запусти `pm2 start code.js --name=sockets`.

По окончанию пропиши `pm2 stop sockets`